# How to get images from a texture atlas with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

A spritesheet image object that contains sprites...

```
var spritesheet = new Image(); spritesheet.src ="foo.png";
```

I would like to be able to get a sub image from that spritesheet variable with the desired x, y, width, and height. And then assign a variable that is the sub image of the spritesheet.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

- Create an in-memory canvas to clip the subsprite pixels from the spritesheet and draw those clipped pixels on that canvas
- Create a new subsprite image from that canvas's dataURL.

Example code (not tested--may need tweeking):

```
var spritesheet = new Image();
spritesheet.onload=function(){

    // specify desired x,y,width,height
    // to be clipped from the spritesheet
    var x=0; 
    var y=0;
    var w=10;
    var h=10;

    // create an in-memory canvas
    var canvas=document.createElement('canvas');
    var ctx=canvas.getContext('2d');

    // size the canvas to the desired sub-sprite size
    canvas.width=w;
    canvas.height=h;

    // clip the sub-sprite from x,y,w,h on the spritesheet image
    // and draw the clipped sub-sprite on the canvas at 0,0
    ctx.drawImage(spritesheet,  x,y,w,h,  0,0,w,y);

    // convert the canvas to an image
    var subsprite=new Image();
    subsprite.onload=function(){ doCallback(subsprite); };
    subsprite.src=canvas.toDataURL();    

}
spritesheet.src ="foo.png";


function doCallback(img){
    // do something with the new subsprite image
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to get multiple sub images and declare a variable for them?

Comment: Sure...Put the above code in a function. Next create an array of {x:,y:,w:,h:,imageObject:new Image()}  objects representing the clips you need. And then feed each object in the array into the function and assign each object's imageObject property as the image created in the function.

Answer (score 3):

Using a `div` with [backgroundPosition](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+backgroundPosition) makes this easy since it will *auto-clip* for us without having to use `overflow`.

For example, here is the [texture atlas](http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/img/icons.png) from the popular *Cookie Clicker* idle game.

Using a *negative* offset for x and y we can select a sub-sprite from the texture atlas:

```js
// Inputs -- change this based on your art
var tw  = 48; // Texture Atlas Tile Width (pixels)
var th  = 48; // Texture Atlas Tile Height (pixels)
var tx  =  3; // tile index x (relative) (column)
var ty  =  2; // tile index y (relative) (row)
var src = 'http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/img/icons.png';

// Calculations -- common code to sub-image of texture atlas
var div = document.getElementById('clip');
var x   = (tx*tw); // tile offset x position (absolute)
var y   = (ty*th); // tile offset y position (absolute)
div.style.width              = tw + 'px';
div.style.height             = th + 'px';
div.style.backgroundImage    = "url('" + src + "')";
div.style.backgroundPosition = '-' + x + 'px -' + y + 'px';

// You don't need the remaining parts. They are only to
// show the sub-sprite in relation to the texture atlas
div.style.border             = "1px solid blue"; // only for demo purposes

// highlight where in the original texture the sub sprite is

var rect    = document.getElementById('sprites').parentNode.getBoundingClientRect();
var hi      = document.getElementById('highlight');
hi.style.zIndex   = 999; // force to be on top
hi.style.position = "absolute";
hi.style.width    = tw + 'px';
hi.style.height   = th + 'px';
hi.style.left     = (rect.left     + x) + 'px';
hi.style.top      = (rect.top + th + y) + 'px'; // skip sub-sprite height
hi.style.border   = '1px solid red';
```

```html
<div id="clip"></div>
<img id="sprites" src="http://orteil.dashnet.org/cookieclicker/img/icons.png">
<div id="highlight"></div>
```

Comment: Love the detailed answer!